# How to implement client side validation in MVC with chosen.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-chosen, client-side-validation

I am using `chosen.js` for multiple selection, implemented with `asp.net` `mvc3`. Client side validation is not working this multi select control.

The way I implement is, using `Html.Dropdownlist` helper and once the dom loaded from JavaScript `$("#dropdown1").chosen()`.

It is replacing the Select with div's.

Below is the code

**callback code**

```
function (data) {
            $("#divnewdata").html(data);

            $("#ddlcode1").chosen({
                disable_search_threshold: 10,
                no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
                disable_search: false,
            });

            $("#ddlCode1_chosen").find('.chosen-choices').removeClass('form-control').addClass('form-control');

            $("#ddlcode2").chosen({
                disable_search_threshold: 10,
                no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
                disable_search: false,
            });

            $("#ddlcode2_chosen").find('.chosen-choices').removeClass('form-control').addClass('form-control');

            $.validator.setDefaults({
                ignore: []
            });

        }
```

**Loading java scripts from layout page**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script>

            $('form').validate({
                ignore: []
            });
    </script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Common/Common.js"></script>
</head>
```

**partial view am trying to download**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#formAddcodes");

        $.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: []
        });
    });
</script>

<link href="~/Content/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Codes/Codes.js"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCodes", "Codes", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formAddcodes" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.code1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.code1, Model.Code1List as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlcode1", multiple = "multiple" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.code1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.code2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.code2, Model.code2List as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlcode2", multiple = "multiple" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.code2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chosen` updates the html by making the original `<select>` element hidden and hidden elements are ignored by default. You can modify this behavior using either the following scripts

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: []
});
```

or

```
$('form').validate({
    ignore: []
});
```

Comment: Then you have not done it correctly. It needs to go after you have loaded the jquery scripts but not in `document.ready` Also which version of jquery are you using? You may need to use `ignore: ""` if its an old version

Comment: Jquery Version is **1.10.2**. Am loading jquery scripts in my Layout page. And the place where am using chosen control is one of the partial view, loading through ajax call.

Comment: Dynamic controls are not validated unless you re-parse the validator. In the success callback you also need to add the following code after you have appended the element to the DOM attached the plugin -  `form.data('validator', null); $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);` (you should have put that information in your question!)

Comment: ok sorry for not mentioning clearly. In my ajax call back after appending content to dom reparsing the form with above code also.Here also once again am doing `$('form').validate({
    ignore: []
});`

Comment: If its still not working, edit your question to show the actual code you have tried. But first comment out the `$("#dropdown1").chosen()` line and make sure its working with the the standard dropdownlist

Comment: First remove all the scripts from the partial view (NEVER put scripts in partials) and move them into the main view  or layout. You still haven't added `form.data('validator', null); $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);` in the success callback (immediately before the `$.validator.setDefaults({` line.)

Comment: And why do you have nonsense like `.removeClass('form-control').addClass('form-control');`. And use `@Html.ListBoxFor(..)` which means you don't need to add `multiple="multiple"` and why do you override the `id` attribute (which would have been `id="code1"` to make it `id="ddlcode1"` instead). But ALWAYS test using the standard html helpers, so initially comment out all code relating to attaching the plugin.

Comment: I also cant see the 2 essential scripts for client side validation - `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` (i.e. `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`)

Comment: Great it worked. Those validation scripts i included in Main View

Comment: @user007 can you please share the final code that works specially the sequence of javascripts and place where you added $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form); etc, I am struggling with this but no luck yet.

Comment: @z, If you have a issue with your code, the ask a question on this site showing the relevant code and indicating what your problem is